# How to extract only final part of window.location.pathname in jQuery? (specifics inside)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is working great, but how can I modify it to only send back the final part of the URL path? For example, this will send back /path/name-of-page with each form submission, but I would like for it to send only **name-of-page**.

```
onFormReady: function($form) {
    $('input[name="urlpath"]').val(window.location.pathname).change();
}
```

Is there any way to merge everything into my original code, like...

```
window.location.pathname.split("/").pop()
```

...or some sort of merging of lastIndexOf within the code I already have? I tried a few of these without luck.

Please provide simple steps, if possible. Thank you.

Comment: `window.location.pathname.split("/").pop()` should work, what's the problem?

Comment: Yes, `window.location.pathname.split("/").pop()` should work as It gave me the result on this page "how-to-extract-only-final-part-of-window-location-pathname-in-jquery-specifics" when I enter this command on console of the browser.

Comment: @Barmar, It will not work if there is a slash at the end of path

Comment: @Achahms, well in that case pop wont work out, simply split the pathname with '/' and take out the second last element, `a=window.location.pathname.split('/')`, then check if `a[a.length-1]==""`, if yes go for `a[a.length-2]` else go for `a[a.length-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **function**:

```
  var lastPart = function($url) {

    var url = $url;

    // Split URL into parts and store them as array 
    var parts = url.split("/");

    // Get value of last part
    var last_part = parts[parts.length - 1];

    // In case there is a '/' at the end
    if(last_part === '') last_part = parts[parts.length - 2];

    return last_part;

  }
```

How to use it:

```
last_part = lastPart(window.location.pathname);
```